# $f:[a,b] \to [0, \infty)$ continuous , then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(\int_a^b \big(f(x)\big)^ndx \Bigg)^{1/n}=\sup \{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to [0, \infty)$ be continuous , then is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(\int_a^b \big(f(x)\big)^ndx \Bigg)^{1/n}=\sup \{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$ ?

Comment: Yes. The $L_p$ norms tend to the $L_{\infty}$ norm, if the function belongs to all of them.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question already solved by Did, I just need to find it.